# Advantages and disadvantages of JPA java.util.Calendar mappings over java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, jpa, calendar

We have certain database date mappings in our entities that are mapped as `java.util.Calendar` like:

```
@Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
@Column( name = "END_DATE" )
private Calendar end;
```

Note, this is currently on Oracle DATE types, which contain date and time information. I currently don't see why a simple `java.util.Date` wouldn't suffice (or even work better).

**Q:**

What are the advantages and disadvantages of mapping database date-time columns as `java.util.Calendar` instead of `java.util.Date`?

One disadvantage of `Calendar` is when having JSF forms

```
<p:calendar value="#{managerBean.selectedEntity.end.time}"
            ...>
</p:calendar>
```

you have to use `end.time`. No problem when displaying, but when submitting and the `Calendar` field `end` is by default null (optional), e.g. on a new blank entity, then the submit will fail with an exception:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /view/blaMasterGrid.xhtml @138,62 value="#{managerBean.selectedEntity.end.time}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null at 
.
.
.
```

So, what are the advantages of `java.util.Calendar` over `java.util.Date` mappings?

Answer (score 2):

A large number of java.util.Date functions are deprecated, and hence it should not be used if your application need to perform many operations on those variable. Joda Time is the most preferable method to work with instead of either java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar

The java.util.Date is left with just three non-deprecated functions which are the constructor, gettime() and settime(). This might cause problem as you progress with code. For the sake of simple mapping, java.util.Date will suffice.